# how to alter view path field plugin

Tags: views, entities

[image]

I Fetched the path field from view using views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) now I made some changes on that path field but I want path field use my data instead of drupal default path value how can I do that.

```
 function view_path_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if($view->id() == 'view_idea_shots_for_home_page' && $view->current_display == 
   'block_3') {
    foreach($view->result as $value){
      $path = $view->field['path']->render($value);
    }
     $path = $path['#markup'];
     $path = get_tiny_url($path);
     kint($path);
  }
}

function get_tiny_url($url)  {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

simply I want to alter path field data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the class `Drupal\node\Plugin\views\field\Path`, add an annotation with a new plugin name `@ViewsField("my_node_path")` and override `render()` to place the new code.

Then add or change the field plugin name in views data:

```
$data['node']['path'] = [
  'field' => [
    'title' => $this->t('Path'),
    'help' => $this->t('The aliased path to this content.'),
    'id' => 'node_path',    // put here 'my_node_path'
  ],
];
```

See [hook_views_data_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/8.4.x).

Comment: so I need to write my logic under render() method rihgt??

Comment: Yes, I suggested to extend the class, but I think this is not necessary, because there is not much code besides that in render() you want to replace. So you can copy it to your own module as well, adjust the plugin name and class namespace and rewrite the code in render().