# How do I override the date filter to filter by years instead of exact date?

Tags: views, 8

I want to add another option to `Date` filter to filter with only years not the exacte date.
So i want to add another radio option here:
[image]
**Like:**
[image]

The above options added by [Date](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21Date.php/class/Date/8.2.x) Filter.
I have tried two ways:

1. Add new filter like date filter:
   **modules/custom/my_module/src/Plugin/views/filter/DateYear.php**

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\NumericFilter;

/**
 * Filter to handle dates stored as a timestamp.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("date_year")
 */
class DateYear extends NumericFilter {
  // Same Code Date class with a little changes. 
}
```

2. I tried to extend `Date` class and alter date filter plugin.

   - I create Class DateYear extending Date filter class:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\Date;
/**
 * Filter to handle dates stored as a timestamp.
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("date_year")
 */
class DateYear extends Date {
  // Override valueForm method..
}
```

- Then i implement `hook_views_plugins_filter_alter` to override class.

```
   /**
 * Implements hook_views_plugins_filter_alter().
 */
function cam_views_views_plugins_filter_alter(array &$plugins) {
  if ($plugins['date']) {
    $plugins['date']['class'] = 'Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\filter\DateYear';
  }
}
```

But none of the above works ?

Comment: What doesn't work, the discovery? Then check the discovered plugins of this plugin type with `drupal plugin:debug views.filter`? At first glance the fully-qualified class name in the second example looks odd, should contain `\Plugin\views`. Also if you introduce a new plugin like in the first example you have to connect it in views data.

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252874/how-to-alter-view-path-field-plugin

Comment: What doesn't work, in both cases my class doesn't called, and I didn't find the filter in views hi ,I already tested the second option with /plugin/views/filter and it doesn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contribute a module for this check it out here:

> This module add views filter by year exact, instead of full date like mm-dd-yyyy you can use date year like yyyy.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_year_filter